# Registry keys for context menu entries written, but no context menu entries

Tags: c#, registry, inno-setup

I think this is a very weird question, but anyway...

I have created two C# applications, `himgr.exe` and `cimgr.exe`. They're installed with Inno Setup, and copied to `C:\Program Files [(x86)]\Imgr Suite`.

They're done to be used through a context menu entry at `explorer.exe`, so I configured the installator to create a few keys in the registry:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\jpegfile\shell\Halve size"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\jpegfile\shell\Halve size\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\himgr.exe"" ""%1"""
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\pngfile\shell\Halve size"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\pngfile\shell\Halve size\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\himgr.exe"" ""%1"""
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\giffile\shell\Halve size"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\giffile\shell\Halve size\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\himgr.exe"" ""%1"""
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\jpegfile\shell\Resize to custom size"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\jpegfile\shell\Resize to custom size\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\cimgr.exe"" ""%1"""
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\pngfile\shell\Resize to custom size"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\pngfile\shell\Resize to custom size\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\cimgr.exe"" ""%1"""
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\giffile\shell\Resize to custom size"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\giffile\shell\Resize to custom size\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\cimgr.exe"" ""%1"""
```

The full installation script is [here](https://gist.github.com/unrar/6151394).

**Note**: I also tried `HKCR\jpegfile` etc. and it worked for me, but...

Neither using the script above (using `HKLM`) nor with `HKCR`, for some people it doesn't work. 4 people out of 6 who have tried it haven't had any problems and it has worked as intended, but for 2 people it hasn't.

The entries were at the registry, but there were no context menu entries.

For one of the testers, the *Edit with GIMP* entry of the `jpegfile` key, although present in registry, wasn't shown in the context menu either. Also, for the same tester, the *Preview* entry for the context menu was shown **twice**.

[In this thread](http://www.den.simlogical.com/denforum/index.php/topic,2082.msg13214.html#msg13214) you have more information about the program itself and the tests. A RAR file with all the files needed for the compilation of the installer is available [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?k4s4mq8oqw04xm6).

This is really worrying me, and we can't find any explanation for why is it not working.

Comment: Most likely, the people whom it didn't work for have had .gif and/or .jpg associated with a different ProgId than "giffile" or "jpegfile".

Comment: Oh thanks! And how can I add a key to the proper ProgId using Inno Setup?

Comment: Could the problem be due to permissions.  You need admin permissions to create keys in HKCR and HKLM

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the people whom it didn't work for have had .gif and/or .jpg associated with a different ProgId than "giffile" or "jpegfile".

You can get Inno to add the registration to whatever the current ProgId association is like so:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Classes\{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg|jpegfile}\shell\Halve size"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Classes\{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg|jpegfile}\shell\Halve size\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\himgr.exe"" ""%1"""
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.png|pngfile}\shell\Halve size"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\classes\{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.png|pngfile}\shell\Halve size\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\himgr.exe"" ""%1"""
```

Abd so on for your other entries.

Bear in mind that if the user later changes their file associations (or installs an application that does so) then these options may disappear again until they re-run your installer.